# How to show dialog forms in c#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, modal-dialog, showdialog

I am using this block of code to show other Form1 as a dialog

```
 private void ShowDialogWindow<T>() where T : Form, new()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        using (Form form = new T())
        {
            form.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }

    ShowDialogWindow<Form1>();// loads form1 as a dialog form
```

The code below is sort of a transparent borderless form that will add a transparent effect to parent form when the child form is active

namespace PopupEffect
{

```
public partial class transparentBg : Form
{
    public transparentBg(Form parent, Form child)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _child = child;

        this.Location = parent.Location;
        this.Size = parent.Size;
        this.ShowDialog();
    }
    public transparentBg(Form child)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _child = child;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.ShowDialog();
    }

    _ = new PopupEffect.transparentBg(this, new Form1());//add the fade effect to the parent form when the child form is active
```

how can i add the transparent block of code to this ShowDialogWindow()

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you rephrase your question, maybe adding some more details on what should be transparent and what `PopupEffect` is or should be? Click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58715717/edit) link to update your question.

Comment: What is  PopupupEffect? ShowDialog blocks the caller until the user close the form. Is that you want, because you say *to show other Dialog forms*... perhaps you may use Show().